# How to create a custom advertisedServices

Tags: corda

I was looking at Corda **Demobench** and I was wondering how to **create custom advertised services** in a Cordapps.

The Demobench provide a lot of services for a node such as:

```
corda.notary.simple --> (simple notary)  
corda.notary.validating --> (validating notary)  
corda.intrest_rates --> (oracle service)  
corda.issuer.CURRENCY  
corda.cash
```

I believe the last two services are custom services that enable the nodes to provide special services like issue cash and use cash.

Please do correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes can advertise a service by listing it in their node configuration file under `extraAdvertisedServiceIds` - see https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html. You can also list the name of the service you wish to offer in the `deployNodes` task - see https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2/samples/irs-demo/build.gradle#L56.

However, Corda is moving away from looking up nodes based on the service they offer. In V2, there are no methods to retrieve a node based on the service it offers. In V3, the concept of services will be removed entirely.

If you check the Oracle Example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples), you'll see that we look up the oracles by name, and not based on the fact that they offer a specific service.

Comment: If the concept of services would be removed then how can I ensure that only one single node would be able to issue assets and others would use them

Comment: You could encode this constraint directly in the contract code or in the flows. Instead of identifying this issuer by their service, you'd identify them simply by name.

Comment: But if I create a constraint then those flows and contract would still be shown on the list. In CoradaDemobench you cant even see the flows in the node if you have not selected that service before initializing the node. Can you point me to some examples that would help me in implementing this?

Comment: You control which flows appear on which nodes simply by installing or not installing the CorDapp jar containing them on a node. See the `deployNodes` task here for example: https://github.com/CaisR3/cordapp-optionv1/blob/master/build.gradle. The Oracle node has the `base` and `oracle` cordapps installed, while the other (non-oracle) nodes have the `base` and `client` cordapps installed.

Comment: So let's say If I want to issue cash from node A and then use that cash in another node then how should I distribute the app so that the same state could be used between both the nodes

Comment: That's the point of the `base` cordapp - it contains the shared state and contract definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification